# Threejs shadows: how do I update a depth material?

Tags: three.js, shader, shadow, depth

I have the following scene:

[image]

As you can see I have shadows activated for a directional light source.
The problem is that when I change the tree top vertices with a vertex shader (using `material.onBeforeCompile`), the shadows don't update automatically

So while trying to solve this issue, I learned that since light sources use depth materials to calculate a shadow map, I should also update the mesh's depth material...

And here's the problem.
Once I set `mesh.customDepthMaterial = new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial();`, the shadows disappear even before I get to change the vertex shader.

I don't know if this is helpful but when I set the mesh's material to be `new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial()`,  without the `onBeforeCompile` function, all the meshes in the scene appeared black

**EDIT: ADDING CODE**

This is a link to the code: [codepen](https://codepen.io/the-roman-one/pen/OJNqZVE)

Search for the function `createObject`, in it there's a segment:

```
let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);

// mesh.customDepthMaterial = new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial();
// mesh.customDepthMaterial.onBeforeCompile = (shader) =>
// {

// }
```

All meshes created in the scene go through this function.
If you uncomment the first commented line, the shadows coming from the sun disappear but the shadows from the pointer remain.

Comment: Can you share some example code?

Comment: @GarrettJohnson sorry it took so long, I added a link to the code in the post, thanks!